# How do I edit CSS files when each file has a .css.gz copy?

Tags: css, gzip

I am trying to edit a Drupal CSS file.  As you can see from my image, each CSS file has an equivalent .css.gz file.

Am i right to assume that most browsers will serve the .css.gz file and not the .css file?
Do i have to edit the .css file and then gzip it somehow, and how do I do this?

[image]

Comment: You can find how to gzip a file with Google. Backup the original files, and try to replace one, then the other to see what works. Tried to search with Google if Drupal does the compression automatically but didn't find anything appropriate. You may have a (performance) plugin handling that in the admin panel.

Comment: You might want to modify your `.htaccess` file to handle the compression of all of your static content for you. This way you can upload a non gzipped file and Apache with compress it for you when a user visits your site. Checkout `mod_deflate`.